# Keep only the top 10 rows of the datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I currently have a datatable which is sorted by a specific column and once the sort has been done I would like to get rid of the rows of data which are not needed at the bottom,

For example, I have 14 rows and only need the top 10, how would I be able to delete the bottom four?

the datatable is queried from a falt file spread sheet file stored in a datatable and then i am sorting the data then only want to take the top 10 rows

Comment: it depends on your RDMS. Please add your database type as a tag to your question.

Comment: How did you populated the `DataTable`?

Comment: something like `datatable.AsEnumerable().Take(10)` might work

Comment: @V4Vendetta, not sure if it works on the sorting order of the rows in the datatable

Comment: Related [Select TOP 5 * from SomeTable, using Dataview.RowFilter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2627695/1577396)

Comment: i have added more detail

Comment: @Steve Should be the case and not if he has done say `datatable.DefaultView.Sort` here the view gets sorted else the table would have the sorted data

Comment: @V4Vendetta, well not in my test. If you work on datatable then you get the record in whatever order the database gives you back. However this will do: `var c = datatable.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(v => v[0]).Take(10);` where v[0] is the sorted field

Comment: @Steve you are right but i think its already sorted as in the question *and once the sort has been done ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq to extract the top 10 record using Take(10) but after you have sorted the datatable

```
var records = datatable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(v => v["FieldToUseAsSortOrder"]).Take(10); 
foreach(DataRow r in records)
{
    // process your records in order
}
```

Of course this will redo the sort against your table, so it's up to you to choose between sorting through the LinQ expression above or loop on your DefaultView rows and remove the unneeded ones

```
for(int x = 10; x < datatable.DefaultView.Count; x++)
{
    datatable.DefaultView[x].Row.Delete();
}
datatable.AcceptChanges();
```

The first approach leave your datatable with all the original rows extracting only the needed one, the second approach will update your datatable removing the unneeded rows (Only in memory of course)

Answer (score 0):

if your database is Sql Server:

```
Delete From VictimTable
       Where ID Not In(
       Select Top 10 ID From VictimTable Order By SomeColumn)
```